# How to set autofocus in angular or angular 2 not angularjs

Tags: angular

I see many posts in how to set autofocus on an input filed in angularjs by creating a directive or HTML autofocus, Is there a quick and easy way to set focus in angular (angular 2, angular 4 etc)

Comment: Do this `elem.focus()`

Comment: Where to place elem.focus(). inside the complaint.ts right

Comment: <input type="text" autofocus> did not worked for me all though its html 5 attribute.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In your html add `#nameit` to get its reference in component code.

```
<input type="text" name="me" #nameit>
```

Then apply auto fouces into it.

```
  @ViewChild('nameit') private elementRef: ElementRef;

  public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.elementRef.nativeElement.focus();
  }
```

Comment: Please note that this can give a horrible user experience in iOS, because the keyboard will automatically show up and cover half of the user's screen. Only use it like this in components where input is mandatory.

Comment: Update: in Angular 4 with Material Design components I did: `@ViewChild('myInput', { read: MatInput }) stateTypeahead: MatInput;` and then this started working: `this.myInput.focus();` (Did not need `nativeElement`

Comment: Hi @Red3, does yours work with Angular 5? I tried but got no luck.

Comment: Try binding the ViewChild to a MatInput iso ElementRef. That way you can directly call MatInput's focus() method.

Comment: for angular 8+ viewchild requires 2 arguments, try this @ViewChild('nameit' , {static: false}) private elementRef: ElementRef;

Answer (score 9):

Aniruddha Das' answer works well in some cases.  However, if this is applied to a template-based form with required validation, you may get the following error:

> ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after >it was checked. Previous value: 'false'. Current value: 'true'.

One solution to this is wrapping the focus() call within ngInit() instead of ngAfterViewInit().  So, extending upon Aniduddha's answer:

In your html add the #namedReference to the component:

```
<input type="text"
    placeholder="Your full name"
    name="name"
    ngModel
    #fullName="ngModel"
    required
    #nameit>
```

Then use onNgInit() to apply auto focus into it:

```
@ViewChild('nameit') private elementRef: ElementRef;

ngOnInit() {
    this.elementRef.nativeElement.focus();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<input id="name" type="text" #myInput />
{{ myInput.focus() }}
```

Add `{{ myInput.focus() }}` into your template.

Comment: NOTICE - this is equivalent to placing focus on `ngOnChanges()` which, in terms of user experience is VERY BAD. your user won't be able to focus away. ever.

Comment: duly noted but if it's the only usable field or button in the page I can think of use cases for this. that being said are there also performance implications or does this ad no strain?

Comment: I agreed with Stavm. This is only usable in case you have only one focusable control, e.g. in popup.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the exemple of the most votted answer, but some times you need to put your focus inside of a setTimeout for make a "async" call. In my case i need to put the setTimeout in a selected filter of mat-autocomplete component of angular material.

my code look like this

```
   setTimeout(() => this.qtdeRef.nativeElement.focus());
```

Answer (score 0):

This one did it for me, as my input element could show or hide depending on some property.

Template:

```
<input #captionElement matInput>
```

Code:

```
@ViewChild('captionElement') captionField: ElementRef;
```

If the item will show/hide (via *ngIf) like:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="editModeCaption; then editCaption else viewCaption" >
</ng-container>
<ng-template #editCaption>
  <mat-form-field>
   <mat-label>Image Caption</mat-label>
     <input  #captionElement matInput>
  </mat-form-field>
</ng-template>
<ng-template #viewCaption>
   ...
</ng-template>
```

Where editModeCaption is a property of your container (tells me whether I am in edit mode or not) component. DO NOT put it on ngAfterViewInit(), but on ngAfterViewChecked (AfterViewChecked interface). like this:

```
ngAfterViewChecked(): void {
  if (this.editModeCaption) {
    this.captionField.nativeElement.focus();
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<input type="text" #textInput placeholder="something" (focus)="someFunction(textInput.value)"/>
```

or

```
<input type="text" #textInput placeholder="something" (keyup.enter)="someMethod(textInput.value)"/>
```

Comment: I don't need a replacement for ng-focus or a function to executed on focus, I want to do autofocus when anyone will be on that page, if that component is there it will focus that input field.