# Angular: Form submit on enter does not work with updateOn: 'submit'

Tags: angular, forms, validation, formgroups

I have a form with 'updateOn: 'submit' since we only need to validate once our user submits. This has, however, caused the submit on enter to stop working: it triggers the validation, but acts as if the form had no values in it and only shows the Validators.required message. When i printed the form into console it also sees the form as empty. When the submit is invoked by clicking on the submit button, everything works well.

Is there a way to either detect the pressing of enter key and programmatically invoke the native submit to trigger validation, or tackle this problem in any smarter way?

I have reproduced it on this Stackblitz link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p4p5k9?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

How to simulate:
 1. type a value into the textfield and hit Submit. The value is seen in the console
 2. Type something else in the textfield and hit enter. The new value hasn't updated, the old value is seen in the console instead.

I need to somehow invoke the programmatic submit on enter so that when the submit() method is invoked in the enterHit subscription, the form already has the new values in it.

Comment: Patel Rushi's last comment is what fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your ts file take one variable

```
isSubmitted:Boolean = false;
```

And give that to particular Validation condition.Example as below

```
  <div *ngIf="testForm.get('amount').errors && submitted" class="text-danger">
      <div *ngIf="testForm.get('amount').errors.required && submitted" class="fontSize12">Amount is
        required
      </div>
  </div>
```

And your button click should be

```
submitForm(form:FormGroup) {
    this.isSubmitted = true;
}
```

Comment: I might have described the problem poorly. When the user presses Enter, ts file can't see the values written in the form, because the native submit hasn't happened yet (the user hasn't clicked the submit button)

Comment: Try to add <form #yourform ="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">

Comment: The method onSubmit() on (ngSubmit) is also only called when the submit button is clicked, it does not react on enter hit. When i tried adding #form="ngForm", the page stopped working, it appears that this piece of code did not work well with the existing formGroup instance

Comment: Ohk got your problem. You have the issue named autofocus. Add Autofocus in any of the fields when the form is generated and then press enter. May it helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42861734/how-to-set-autofocus-in-angular-or-angular-2-not-angularjs

Comment: I'm sorry that I am still leading you on. We already have autofocus on the first input field and even when we manually fill the data in the field and press enter, the submit does not happen. 
We even have subscribed on the enterhit property and call our programmatic submit (which extracts data and besides submitting it it also pushes them to our rxjs store). This same programmatic submit is also called on our ngSubmit().

Comment: What happens is this:
1.if the user types data into inputfields on our forms and clicks the submit button manually, the this.form.value has its data written in it and our submit() method is called from ngSubmit, puts the data to our store and whatnot.
2. if the user types the data into inputfields on our forms and presses enter, the form does not register this operation the same as pressing the submit button, then our "enterhit" subscription is triggered and calls the programmatic submit(), which looks into this.form.value and sees empty values, because the submit button hadn't been pressed.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p4p5k9?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts
when you write something and hit submit, value is written in the console. When you write something else and hit enter, the old value is still written in the console

Comment: (keyup.enter)='$event.target.blur();propagateEnter()' it fixes your issue

Answer (score 0):

You can create a boolean variable hasSubmittedOnce and set its initial value to false and on form submit change its value to true

```
private hasSubmittedOnce: boolean = false;

onSubmit() {
 if(!this.hasSubmittedOnce) {
   this.hasSubmittedOnce = true;
 }
}
```

after that update your validation check, add hasSubmittedOnce condition, if hasSubmittedOnce is true then only validate values and show error messages

Comment: I probably described it a bit confusingly. I have a problem that unless the user clicks on the submit button, the ts file does not know any of the values in the form and sees this.form.value as empty, because it only updates its values on submit button click. When the user hits the Enter key instead of clicking the button, the submit button does not react and validations triggered on enter key also see the form as empty.